# Unable to create ionic app with Ionic Start, receiving Unexpected end of JSON error

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a new ionic app using `ionic start`, when I provide a project name the installation begins but I received the below error in the VS Code console:

```
> npm.cmd i
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...{"mocha":"~1.12.0","c'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\11342\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-03T19_10_04_787Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.
```

Can someone please tell me what may be causing this issue, & how it can be resolved?

Comment: Can you show the relevant details from the log file? Also try cleaning the npm cache using `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: That command resolved the issue